# Open directions func not opening apple maps programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am working on a project right now and am stuck on the final part. I have designed an app with 20 custom annotations to be used by our wedding guests to find nearby restaurants, bars, coffee shops, etc. There are various custom annotation to identify what each location is. It also asks for users current location so they can find things nearby. I would like to be able to click on the annotations and have our friends and family be able to get directions from their current location to the annotation. It seems like the best way to do this is by opening up the apple maps app with my latitude and longitude coordinates in my custom point annotations. My code though does not seem to open that maps app at all. I have added a right call out, I have looked through every since question old and new asking about this and can not find a solution. Any advice will be much appreciated as this is my first real swift app. Below is my current open directions function. Thank you in advance for any help or insight.

```
    func openDirections(_ address :String?) {

    self.geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address!, completionHandler: { (placemarks :[CLPlacemark]?, error :NSError?) -> Void in

        let placemark = placemarks![0] as CLPlacemark

        let destinationPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: placemark.location!.coordinate, addressDictionary: placemark.addressDictionary as? [String:NSObject])

        let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: placemark.location!.coordinate, addressDictionary:nil))
        mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving])

        let startingMapItem = MKMapItem.forCurrentLocation()
        let destinationMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: destinationPlacemark)

        let directionsRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()
        directionsRequest.transportType = .automobile
        directionsRequest.source = startingMapItem
        directionsRequest.destination = destinationMapItem

        let directions = MKDirections(request: directionsRequest)

        directions.calculate(completionHandler: { (response :MKDirectionsResponse?, error :NSError?) -> Void in

            let route = response!.routes[0] as MKRoute

            if route.steps.count > 0 {

                for step in route.steps {

                    print(step.instructions)

                }
            }

            self.mapView!.add((route.polyline), level: MKOverlayLevel.aboveRoads)
            } as! MKDirectionsHandler)
        } as! CLGeocodeCompletionHandler)
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to open the Maps app? You have a `MKMapView` right? You can use that, and make custom annotations. You can use the `CoreLocation` framework to get, and update the current user's location. I guess I don't understand why you would want to force the user to go from your app to the Apple Maps app when it's not necessary.

Comment: @Pierce I would be happy with that option as well, but am having a hard time figuring that out as well after searching through multiple tutorials / questions on SO. I can't seem to find a good solution to do this within the app with multiple annotations. Any suggestion on the best way to tackle that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You know what it's a lot to learn, and way more than I could tell you in a comment or answer. Check out this free tutorial. It should go over everything you could need https://www.raywenderlich.com/136165/core-location-geofencing-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Go ahead and delete everything you wrote and do some research on how to write a new, better, cleaner function. Here is what worked for me and I hope it helps someone else.

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view:MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

    let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: view.annotation!.coordinate, addressDictionary: nil)
    let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
    let launchOptions = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeTransit]
    self.title = title
    mapItem.name = title
    mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: launchOptions)
}
```